# Mixed size CSS text in different lines

Tags: html, css

I need to do this, using CSS (the one in the left is the intended design the one on the right is the actual output)

[image]

Now I'm trying to make this using this markup

```
        <div class="layout__in-block">
            <h2 id="title__two" class="presentation__big-titles">
                <span>great</span>
                <br/>
                <span>experiences</span>
                <br/>
                <span>for users</span>
            </h2>
        </div>
```

And then, using something like this in the CSS I style the text

```
#title__two > span:nth-child(1) {
    font-size: 117px;
}

#title__two > span:nth-child(3) {
    font-size: 56px;
}

#title__two > span:nth-child(5) {
    font-size: 73px;
}
```

But the problem is that the `<br/>` and the separated elements inside the each `<span>` are hard to control.

Any suggestion on how to solve this? Any other suggestion about the code is welcomed.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "hard to control."?

Comment: What do you mean by *separated elements*?

Comment: make span {diplay :block } and use word-spacing and line-height with justified text

Comment: If you don't want to change your HTML (which I suggest you change and remove <br /> tags) use nth-of-type instead of nth-child. Then you can index them 1, 2 and 3

Comment: Hard to control, because the `<br>` adds space, also each one is on a separated `<span/>` element, so `line-height` does not do what I want. I edited the code and example for more clarity. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `span`s to `div`s and drop the `br` tag.

As both `span` and `div` has no specific semantics of its own, `divs` are block-level and `spans` are inline.

Block-level : `display: block;`, inline : `display: inline`

The distance between the lines and letters is adjusted using `line-height` and `letter-spacing`.

```css
#title__two {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 0.85;
}

#title__two > div:nth-child(1) {
    color: red;
    font-size: 50px;
    letter-spacing: 14px;
}

#title__two > div:nth-child(2) {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

#title__two > div:nth-child(3) {
    color: green;
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout__in-block">
  <h2 id="title__two" class="presentation__big-titles">
    <div>great</div>
    <div>experiences</div>
    <div>for users</div>
  </h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure! Get rid of the `<br>`'s and declare this CSS:

```
span { display:block; }
```

Answer (score 1):

For the differences in line height, may I suggest using a small font size for the h2 and `line-height:1ex` for the spans.

And if you don't want to worry about the number of `<br>`s, first target all the spans with just `span` and follow that with a `:first-child` and then a `:last-child` with specifics for those two spans. Then it won't matter if there are `<br>`s or not.

```css
#title__two {
  font: bold 12px 'Arial Narrow';
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
#title__two > span {
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height:1ex;
}
#title__two > span:first-child {
  font-size: 125px;
}
#title__two > span:last-child {
  font-size: 73px;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout__in-block">
  <h2 id="title__two" class="presentation__big-titles">
    <span>great</span>
    <br/>
    <span>experiences</span>
    <br/>
    <span>for users</span>
  </h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the end effect you're after, you'll probably want to do something a little more dynamic. There are some great js solutions for doing this. Take a look at:

- http://freqdec.github.io/slabText/
- http://www.zachleat.com/web/bigtext-makes-text-big/

Comment: I was looking for a more "handmade" solution using CSS but your suggestion are really interesting. Definitely I'm going to check those one.